# Fill in Basic Colours in Qgis

Tags: qgis, interpolation, color, tin

I'm trying to fill in a TIN interpolation to be a full 1:2 rectangle. When the interpolation is finished, the areas with no land cut off in the corner leaving it transparent, which causes issues for what I use the maps for. The gaps don't occupy any land so it would be as simple as adding in the same colour that represents 0 altitude.